# Why does testpy work only with PYTHONPATH set?

Tags: python

I noticed nose and test.py cannot run tests in `tests` unless PYTHONPATH is set. Spefifically, it cannot import my modules.

Why is this happening?

```
(venv)suyati@SUYPC021:~/dev/proj/backend/proj$ PYTHONPATH=`pwd` py.test
============================================= test session starts =============================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.9 -- py-1.4.30 -- pytest-2.7.2
rootdir: /home/dev/proj/backend/proj, inifile: 
collected 2 items 

default_test.py .
tests/default_test.py .

========================================== 2 passed in 0.29 seconds ===========================================
```

Without PYTHONPATH.

This shows `default_test` in `tests` failing to import `commons` in top-level.

```
(venv)suyati@SUYPC021:~/dev/proj/backend/proj$ py.test
============================================= test session starts =============================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.9 -- py-1.4.30 -- pytest-2.7.2
rootdir: /home/dev/proj/backend/proj, inifile: 
collected 1 items / 1 errors 

default_test.py .

=================================================== ERRORS ====================================================
___________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/default_test.py ____________________________________
tests/default_test.py:3: in <module>
    from commons import ZONES
E   ImportError: No module named commons
====================================== 1 passed, 1 error in 0.47 seconds ======================================
```

Comment: Does `from commons import ZONES` work in the interpreter? Have you actually installed that module?

Comment: @jonrsharpe of course!